# Wait for Mouse Click Inside While Loop

Tags: swift, macos, sprite-kit

I am working with Sprite Kit for an OS X project and I couldn't figure out how to pause my while loop until a mouse click. What I want is something like this:

```
while (i < 50){
    print(i)
    i += 1
    waitForMouseClick()
}
```

Comment: That will block the main thread and your application won't be able to receive the mouse click.

Comment: So do you have any suggestions to achieve that kind of behaviour?

Comment: The behavior you are looking for is a bit complex.  What you have to do is keep your application's main event loop running so that mouse events are sent to your program, while at the same time keep track of the context of your loop.  By in large it appears that you need to spend some time learning a bit more about OS event handling.  That or you need to provide a larger context in your question about what effect you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: The effect I am trying to accomplish is exactly like in question. I have a very basic while loop, I am using it to manipulate an array. After each turn I show array data on screen and after that I want to wait for user input to proceed to next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it using a GCD background queue and a semaphore. Might be helpful for other people reading this.

```
// CREATE A BACKGROUND QUEUE AND SEMAPHORE
let bgQueue = dispatch_queue_create("myQueue", nil)
let semaphore = dispatch_semaphore_create(0) 

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
    //DISPATCH CODE BLOCK TO QUEUE
    dispatch_async(bgQueue, {
        //THIS WILL GRAB YOUR SEMAPHORE
        dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_NOW)
        var i: Int = 0
        while (i<50){
            i += 1
            //BLOCK
            dispatch_semaphore_wait(self.semaphore, DISPATCH_TIME_FOREVER)
            print(i)
        }
    })
}

override func mouseDown(theEvent: NSEvent) {
    //RELEASE SEMAPHORE
    dispatch_semaphore_signal(semaphore)
}
```

Comment: Will you care to explain which class are you implementing? otherwise I don't understand what does mouseDown override?